# Starting items for investigator not available

Tags: eldritch-horror

During a recent game, a player was defeated. He chose another investigator but when he came to receive the starting items, we realised that they were actually with another investigator in the game.

What should happen in that case? Does the new investigator just miss out on those items or do they take them from the other investigator?

Answer (score 7):

If the items are unavailable, the new investigator cannot take them.

From [the official errata & FAQ](https://images-cdn.fantasyflightgames.com/ffg_content/eldritch-horror/support/EH%20Errata%20&%20FAQ%202015-01-23.pdf):

> **Q.** What happens if a new investigator’s starting possessions are
>   being used by another investigator?
>
> **A.** When a player chooses a new investigator, he receives
>   that investigator’s starting possessions from the decks,
>   discard piles, or reserve. If the starting possessions are not
>   in these places, such as if another investigator or a defeated
>   investigator has them, the new investigator does not start
>   with those possessions.

Answer (score 3):

If the items are not available in the card stack, the new investigator does not receive those items. Doesn't matter how they've been pulled out of the stack.